# My function is returning undefined in Active Directory for node

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

Does anyone know how to return auth in the following function? It is returning null at the moment. I tried to use async await and other many things, but still having hard time to return anything. Thanks for the help!

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: myurl,
  baseDN: 'CN=Users,DC=usdtl,DC=com',
  username: my-username,
  password: my-pass }
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
ad.authenticate(userPrincipalName, password, (err, auth) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    return auth;
  }
  if (auth) {
    console.log(auth)
    return auth
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the return value of a callback, which is what you're trying to do. Instead, you can set a variable first, then assign the variable to that value, as in:

```js
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: myurl,
  baseDN: 'CN=Users,DC=usdtl,DC=com',
  username: my-username,
  password: my-pass }
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

var result; // Right here

ad.authenticate(userPrincipalName, password, (err, auth) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    result = auth;
  }
  if (auth) {
    console.log(auth)
    result = auth;
  }
})
```

Then you can use `result` later on. However, since JavaScript is asynchronous, make sure that you get the value of `result` after the authenticate callback is completed. You can implement something like [`deasync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync).

Answer (score 0):

That is great. I have never heard about deasync. Is there any other way to return result of callback from the following class? Because I have been trying to make deasync work, but it is not working. I am calling this class function in another place.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
 export class AuthService {
  async authenticateUser(username, password) {
    let isAuthenticated: boolean = false
    var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
    var config = { url: 'my_url',
     baseDN: 'CN=Users,DC=usdtl,DC=com' }
    var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
   ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
   if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    return err;
  }
  if (auth) {
    console.log('Authenticated!');
    isAuthenticated = auth
  }
});
} 
}
```